# How to create a regular expression to match first characters in a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression for two scenarios the scenarios are

First I have to return true if the given characters matches the start of the sentence.

For example:

Sentence is    `"<b>your question</b>"`

If the user gives `Yo` I have to  return true.

and also it should not be case sensitive.

2nd scenario is if given characters matches in any place of the string

i have to return the 
string

example

Sentence is `<b>your question</b>"`.
if the user gives `ue` i have to return true.

Comment: Your first sentence says "match the start", the fourth says "which contains", and the last says "which match". Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: in both your scenarios, you are doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

For case insensitiveness use `i` modifier.

Use this to match everything:

```
/^yo.*/i
```

And if you test the string,

you can do it with this way:

```
/^yo/i.test("your question");// returns true if it starts with 'yo' or else returns false
```

The above will work

You can store a variable where the user input will be present and you can concatenate it with `.*`

Comment: This needs to be anchored to line start, per the OP's specifications. And the `.*` is not necessary if you're simply deciding which line to match. If you need to actually match the entire line, then of course it is needed.

Comment: Thanks @AmitJoki and for what expression i have to use for my 2nd scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For any start, you can check it as follows:

`^your_string.*`

The symbol `^` can be used to check matching for the start of a string

For example, `'^yo.*'` will match for `"your question"`

Comment: No, it will only match `yo` at the beginning of the string and not the rest of the string

Comment: The OP's first paragraph: "sentence if the given characters match the start of the given sentence." Although I agree it's overall the question is not so clear.